# highcharts (using csv data) not loading until refreshing the page, sometimes i even have to refresh several times

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I'm using html, css and javascript for the project. The server is set up locally including node, express and highcharts.

In my html i have a div container, that i'm referencing in my highcharts function. The data i'm using in the highchart come from a csv file. I wrote a simple getData function, that parses the data into an array. And at the top of the highchartsfunction, i'm using await getData, so the chart can only be rendered after getting the data for it. All functions are async. On that one page i'm having seven charts, all constructed using the syntax following below, each with its own getData function and div container.

**Two problems:**

Problem No.1:
The charts are not getting displayed until i refresh the page and often times i even have to refresh it several times, till every chart is getting shown at a time (Like 20 times). The functions are all executed, i checked that in the console.

Problem No.2:
I would like to write this dynamically, as i want to have multiple pages on my website, each using its own csv file, but basically the same code.

***Edit:**

From time to time i receive: "Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13/" in the console, but as i keep refreshing it changes the line/js it is referencing to. It always is the part of the highcharts function, in which i give it its container `Highcharts.chart('hammerchart', {`. I checked this error and what it sais is basically, that the script can't find a container with the #id. Which i don't understand as im using "DOMContentLoaded". I tried the "load" event instead, which solved the error #13, but ended up in no chart getting displayed at all without any error message.

***Edit2:**

Until now i only used firefox to view my website. I checked Chrome aswell and here i don't have any error message, but it also never shows any of the charts aswell at all.

If someone could help me out here, i would be really happy, as i tried to fix this for days now with no success. I'm also open for suggestions, regarding the handling of my data. Thank you veeeery much in advance!!

Code:

CSV Data sample

```
2015,2.5,7.2,1.6,6.5,2.2
2016,3.5,7.6,2.6,9.3,1.2
2017,2.5,7.2,1.6,6.5,2.2
2018,3.5,7.6,2.6,9.3,1.2
2019,2.5,7.2,1.6,6.5,2.2
```

HTML

```
   <div id="hammerchart">
   </div>
```

CSS

```
#hammerchart{
    width:49%;
    height: 500px;
    margin:0.5%;
    margin-top:50px;
    flex: 1 1 600px;
}
```

Javascript - first declaration of the arrays, then my parsing function, splitting the csv by linebreaks and commas. Then i'm using parseFloat(), so that i don't have strings in it. In the highcharts function i'm using await getData and DOMContentloaded, to make sure both html and my data are ready.

```
const years = [];
const columntwos = [];
const columnthrees = [];
const columnfours = [];
const columnfives = [];
const columnsixs = [];


async function getDataone() {
    const response = await fetch('/javascripts/hammerchart.CSV');
    const data = await response.text();

    const table = data.split('\n');
    table.forEach(row => {
        const columns = row.split(',');
        const year = columns[0];
        years.push(year);
        const columntwo = columns[1];
        columntwos.push(parseFloat(columntwo));
        const columnthree = columns[2];
        columnthrees.push(parseFloat(columnthree));
        const columnfour = columns[3];
        columnfours.push(parseFloat(columnfour));
        const columnfive = columns[4];
        columnfives.push(parseFloat(columnfive));
        const columnsix = columns[5];
        columnsixs.push(parseFloat(columnsix));
    });
};


async function hammerchart() {
    await getDataone();
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        Highcharts.chart('hammerchart', {
          chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Data'
          },
          subtitle: {
            text: ''
          },
          credits: {
            text: 'highcharts',
          },
          xAxis: [{
            categories: years,
            plotBands: [{ // visualize
                from: 4.5,
                to: 6,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
            }],
            crosshair: true
          }],
          yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
              format: '{value}$',
              style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
              }
            },
            title: {
              text: 'Amount in $',
              style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
              }
            }
          }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
              text: 'Ratio in %',
              style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
              }
            },
            labels: {
              format: '{value} %',
              style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
              }
            },
            opposite: true
          }],
          tooltip: {
            shared: true
          },
          legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor:
              Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || // theme
              'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)'
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'columntwo',
            type: 'areaspline',
            data: columntwos,
            tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: '$'
            }
          }, {
            name: 'columnthree',
            type: 'areaspline',
            data: columnthrees,
            tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: '$'
            }
          }, {
            name: 'columnfour',
            type: 'areaspline',
            data: columnfours,
            tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: '$'
            }
          }, {
            name: 'columnfive',
            type: 'column',
            data: columnfives,
            tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: '$'
            }
          }, {
            name: 'columnsix',
            type: 'spline',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: columnsixs,
            tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: '%'
            }
          }]
        }); 
    }); 
};


hammerchart();
```

Comment: Are you sure the event listener code is executed every time?

Comment: I checked all my "highcharts-functions", i placed the addEventListener in each of them.

Comment: Have you considered to use the Highcharts `data-module` which provides downloading and parsing CSV data into Highcharts charts? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.csv

Comment: Thank you for the response Sebastian! I have considered doing that, but i wanted to write the function myself to practice coding (relatively new to it) and to be able to customize it more in case i need to in the future. And since my function parsed the csv correctly, i sticked to it. Or at least i think it does so. If no one finds a solution for my problem in the next time, i'll try to use the data-module just to be sure if this fixes my problem.

Comment: Ok, then I dug into your code a little and I think that you need to use the `Promise` to make your async function works properly. Basic demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aqc2bzo6/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise